# Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jasmine

I am using jasmine to test my asynchronous function. I am getting following error.

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within 5000ms (set by
>   jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)

I tried to print data resolved from my function. It's printing on the console and after that i am getting above error.

```
funtion test(){
    return new Promise(funtion(resolve,reject){
        resolve({id:1})
    })
}

describe("test function",funtion(){
    it("testing",test().then(function(data,err){
        console.log("resolved Data = ",data)
        expect(data).toEqual({id:1}))
    }))
})
```

Above function is not my exact function. This is just an example.
I am getting value of data in CMD, and after that i am getting

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within 5000ms (set by
>   jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)

If my data is already resolved then why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to ensure that the test is finished according to jasmine standards. The easiest way to do this is to use a `done` parameter. It would be like this:

```
describe("test function",funtion(){
    it("testing",done => {
        test().then(function(data,err){
            console.log("resolved Data = ",data)
            expect(data).toEqual({id:1}))
            done();
        }))
    })
})
```

You just need to make sure that `done()` is invoked when the test is finished.